# How to create a view with multiple select queries that returns multiple rows in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-pivot

I have a table like this in Oracle
table name: links

```
|url             |category|
|----------------|--------|
|www.google.com  |search  |
|----------------|--------|
|www.facebook.com|Social  |
|----------------|--------|
|www.twiter.com  |Social  |
|----------------|--------|
```

and I have to create a view like this

```
|search          |Social          |
|----------------|----------------|
|www.google.com  |www.facebook.com|
|----------------|----------------|
|                |www.twiter.com  |
|----------------|----------------|
```

I have tried the following sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1 AS(
    SELECT(
        (SELECT * FROM Links WHERE category='Search'),
        (SELECT * FROM Links WHERE category='Social')
    ) FROM Dual);
```

but it returns the following error:

> missing right parentheses

when I try to run the following section of the sql

```
SELECT(
        (SELECT * FROM Links WHERE category='Search'),
        (SELECT * FROM Links WHERE category='Social')
    ) FROM Dual;
```

It returns the following error:

> Signle subquery returns multiple rows.

Please somebody help me. And also let me know if it is possible at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PIVOT` clause including analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT "search", "Social"
  FROM (
        SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY url) AS rn
          FROM t
        )
 PIVOT
    (
     MAX(url) FOR category IN ( 'search' AS "search", 'Social' AS "Social" )
    )
 ORDER BY rn
```

and if the `SELECT` statement is prepended by this part `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1 AS`, then you'll have a new database view with name `v1` returning the content of that statement by

```
SELECT * FROM v1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=69b755d10e94a495f88dd0016d215276)</kbd>

**Update :** You have still an option to make the pivot *dynamic* versus upcoming different category values than the current ones. Create a function(or procedure) including `REFCURSOR` such as ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Categories_RS RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||category||''' AS "'||LOWER(category)||'"' , ',' )
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY category )
    INTO v_str
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT category
            FROM t
          );

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT *
     FROM (
           SELECT t.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY url) AS rn
             FROM t
          )
    PIVOT
    (
     MAX(url) FOR category IN ( '|| v_str ||' )
    )
    ORDER BY rn';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
```

and then run the this code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Categories_RS;
PRINT rc
```

from *SQL Developer*'s Command Line in order to see the result set.

Comment: How can I get rid of the category values 'social' and 'search' from being hard coded? these values will be populated dynamically and may change.